# How can i schedule reoccurring deposit from users phantom wallet

Tags: transactions

I have requirement to schedule the token transfer(ex usdc) from one solana account to another.

For example user will sign multiple future transactions and dapp will draw usdc based on the date of future transaction which user signed. Is it possible.?

Answer (score 1):

The chain does not natively provided these capabilities, but there exist other products like https://www.clockwork.xyz/ to do that for you

Comment: If I'm not mistaken or things have changed since, clockwork is no longer in active development. I was looking into this feature as well and saw this thread when looking for answers.. https://twitter.com/time_composer/status/1695852843633172489